# error: request for member 'arreglo' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, array

El programa intenta implementar un arreglo con tope pero envia error con un mensaje que dice:

> error: request for member 'arreglo' in something not a structure or union

¿Cómo se puede resolver este error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define N 30
typedef struct {  int arre[N];
int tope; 
} ArregloConTope;
/* función que me dice si el arreglo ya se llenó */
bool EstaLleno (ArregloConTope act)
{
    bool lleno = false; 
    if (act.tope == N)
        lleno = true;
    return lleno; 
}
/* procedimiento que inserta un valor en el arreglo con tope */
/* precondición: el arreglo no debe estar lleno */
void Insertar (ArregloConTope *act, int valor) 
{
    /* inserto el valor contra el tope y luego lo incremento, como forma de indicar que ahora tengo un valor más */
    int posicion = act->tope;
    act.arreglo[posicion] = valor;
    act->tope++;
}
int main(){
    ArregloConTope *act; int valor;
    int op;
    printf("\t\tBienvenido al programa de arreglo con tope\n");
    printf("1.Insertar elemento\n");
    printf("2.Verificar si el vector esta lleno\n");
    printf("Ingrese una opcion ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    switch(op){
    case 1:
        Insertar(act, valor);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("%d", EstaLleno(*act));
    default:
        printf("Opcion no valida");   
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segun la definición de estructura este tiene 2 campos: `arre` y `tope`, pero tu en la instrucción: `act.arreglo[posicion] = valor;` quieres usar `arreglo` que no es parte de la estructura, ademas act es un puntero en dicha funcion por lo que lo correcto es usar: `act->arre[posicion] = valor;`

Comment: Hago lo que tu me dijiste pero tira error act y valor no inicializadas. La inicio en 0 y el programa se cuelga

Comment: Ese es otro error, has una depuracion, y revisa en que punto se genera el error.

Comment: En el main. Lo que se me ocurrió es pedirle al usuario el valor de la variable valor pero la variable act sigue sin inicializarse

Comment: No uses un puntero, no es necesario, inicializo asi: `ArregloConTope act; int valor;` y despues cambia a `Insertar(&act, valor);` y `printf("%d", EstaLleno(act));`

Comment: o sino debes inicializarlo como `act = new ArregloConTope;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura define un miembro llamado `arre`:

```
typedef struct {
  int arre[N];  // <<--- AQUI!!!
  int tope; 
} ArregloConTope;
```

Y sin embargo luego intentas acceder al miembro `arreglo`:

```
void Insertar (ArregloConTope *act, int valor) 
{
    int posicion = act->tope;
    act.arreglo[posicion] = valor; // <<--- AQUI!!!
    act->tope++;
}
```

La solución es tan sencilla como sustituir `arre` por `arreglo` o viceversa.

Por otro lado fíjate que en el `main` estás declarando un puntero sin inicializar:

```
int main(){
    ArregloConTope *act; // <<--- Declaras puntero sin inicializar
    int valor;
    int op;
    printf("\t\tBienvenido al programa de arreglo con tope\n");
    printf("1.Insertar elemento\n");
    printf("2.Verificar si el vector esta lleno\n");
    printf("Ingrese una opcion ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    switch(op){
    case 1:
        Insertar(act, valor); // <<--- Y aqui lo usas
```

Con eso la aplicación va a acceder (mediante el puntero) a memoria que no le pertenece y el Sistema Operativo, para evitar que corrompas memoria, va a matar el proceso. El resultado es un bonito error de segmentación y la aplicación al garete.

Para este caso en concreto no es necesario que uses memoria dinámica, así que de momento yo me la ahorraría (de momento bastante hay con entender el resto del lenguaje). Aun así no hay que olvidar inicializar las variables correctamente para evitar comportamientos extraños:

```
int main()
{
  ArregloConTope act;
  act.tope = 0; // <<--- Importante

  // ...

  Insertar(&act,valor);

  // ...

  printf("%d", EstaLleno(act));
}
```

Por cierto, nota que en ningún momento le estás pidiendo al usuario que rellene la variable `valor`... luego no te quejes si te rellena el arreglo con basura.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste, pido al usuario que lea la variable valor y el programa llega hasta ahí. La ventana queda abierta pero el programa no hace más nada.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Si no encierras la lógica del main dentro de un bucle solo se va a ejecutar una vez... La respuesta trata el problema que has planteado y, a modo de bonus, te he indicado lo de la variable `valor`... de lo que te quejas ahora es de funcionalidad que te falta por implementar... no de errores en el código.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí está el programa completo funcionando.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
/* defino un tipo que representa un arreglo con tope de enteros */
#define N 30
typedef struct {
int arre[N];
int tope;
} ArregloConTope;
/* función que me dice si el arreglo ya se llenó */
bool EstaLleno (ArregloConTope act)
{
    bool lleno = false; 
    if (act.tope == N)
        lleno = true;
    return lleno; 
}
/* procedimiento que inserta un valor en el arreglo con tope */
/* precondición: el arreglo no debe estar lleno */
void Insertar (ArregloConTope *act, int valor) 
{
    /* inserto el valor contra el tope y luego lo incremento, como forma de indicar que ahora tengo un valor más */
    int posicion = act->tope;
    act->arre[posicion] = valor;
    act->tope++;
}
/* procedimiento que muestra el arreglo completo*/
/* precondición: el arreglo debe tener al menos un elemento */
void MostrarArreglo (ArregloConTope act){
int x;
for(x=0;x<act.tope;x++)
{
printf("%d ", act.arre[x]);
}
getchar();
}

int main()
{
ArregloConTope act;
int valor;
int op;
act.tope = 0;
while(true){
system("cls");
printf("\t\tBienvenido al programa de arreglo con tope\n");
printf("1.Insertar elemento\n");
printf("2.Mostrar arreglo\n");
printf("3.Verificar si el vector esta lleno\n");
printf("4.Salir\n");
printf("Ingrese una opcion ");
scanf("%d",&op);
switch(op)
{
case 1:
if (act.tope != N){
printf("Ingrese valor ");
scanf("%d", &valor);
Insertar(&act, valor);
}else{
printf("Se lleno el arreglo");
getch();
}
break;
case 2:
MostrarArreglo(act);
getchar();
break;
case 3:
if (EstaLleno(act))
printf("El arreglo esta lleno");
else
printf("Aun queda espacio");
getch();
break;
case 4:
getchar();
return 0;
default:
printf("Opcion no valida");
}
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```